# Android Mp chart set Custom X Axis for dates

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I am using mpchart for android version v3.0.3. I am trying to set Custom x-axis value with respect to date and unable to achieve the desired result.

The Value for my Bar Entry is as follows:

```
[Entry, x: 20.0 y: 21.0, Entry, x: 23.0 y: 22.0, Entry, x: 17.0 y: 23.0, Entry, x: 11.0 y: 24.0, Entry, x: 61.0 y: 26.0, Entry, x: 39.0 y: 27.0, Entry, x: 19.0 y: 28.0, Entry, x: 18.0 y: 29.0, Entry, x: 16.0 y: 30.0, Entry, x: 13.0 y: 0.0, Entry, x: 11.0 y: 2.0, Entry, x: 12.0 y: 3.0, Entry, x: 39.0 y: 4.0, Entry, x: 25.0 y: 5.0, Entry, x: 16.0 y: 6.0, Entry, x: 29.0 y: 7.0, Entry, x: 30.0 y: 8.0, Entry, x: 48.0 y: 9.0, Entry, x: 18.0 y: 10.0, Entry, x: 36.0 y: 11.0, Entry, x: 42.0 y: 12.0, Entry, x: 46.0 y: 13.0, Entry, x: 70.0 y: 14.0, Entry, x: 48.0 y: 15.0, Entry, x: 14.0 y: 16.0, Entry, x: 23.0 y: 17.0, Entry, x: 16.0 y: 18.0, Entry, x: 13.0 y: 19.0, Entry, x: 27.0 y: 20.0, Entry, x: 7.0 y: 21.0, Entry, x: 25.0 y: 23.0, Entry, x: 9.0 y: 24.0]
```

The desired value for the entries I want to set on the x-axis is as follows:

```
[22 May , 23 May , 24 May , 25 May , 27 May , 28 May , 29 May , 30 May , 31 May , 01 Jun , 03 Jun , 04 Jun , 05 Jun , 06 Jun , 07 Jun , 08 Jun , 09 Jun , 10 Jun , 11 Jun , 12 Jun , 13 Jun , 14 Jun , 15 Jun , 16 Jun , 17 Jun , 18 Jun , 19 Jun , 20 Jun , 21 Jun , 22 Jun , 24 Jun , 25 Jun ]
```

The Code for setting custom X-Axis values is as follows:

```
public class CustomXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
    ArrayList<String> mIndexForXaxis;

    public CustomXAxisValueFormatter(ArrayList<String> indexForXaxis){
        this.mIndexForXaxis = indexForXaxis;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        AppLogger.i("Print index values: "+mIndexForXaxis);
        String returnIndex = null;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < mIndexForXaxis.size(); i++){
            AppLogger.i("Print index values: "+mIndexForXaxis.get(i));
            returnIndex = mIndexForXaxis.get(i);
        }

        return returnIndex;
    }
}
```

Where I am passing the above the array of dates as indexForXaxis for e.g 22 May etc in this class.

However, the graph which is reflected is as follows

[image]

I understand its taking only last value from the index list. What is the proper way of reflecting the dates then?.

Comment: Here you have two bar graoh? calories graph making issue?

Answer (score 2):

in kotlin:

```
val labels = mutableListOf<String>()
labels.add("1 Jan")
labels.add("2 Jan")
labels.add("3 Apr")
labels.add("5 Jun")
labels.add("10 Des")

val datas = mutableListOf<Entry>()
datas.add(Entry(0f, 20f))
datas.add(Entry(1f, 40f))
datas.add(Entry(2f, 30f))
datas.add(Entry(3f, 70f))
datas.add(Entry(4f, 20f))

val xAxis = linechart.getXAxis()
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM); 
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
xAxis.labelCount = labels.size // important
xAxis.setSpaceMax(0.5f) // optional
xAxis.setSpaceMin(0.5f) // optional
xAxis.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
    override
    fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
            // value is x as index
            return labels[value.toInt()]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it. I hope this solution helps you,

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setTextSize(10f);
xAxis.setTextColor(Color.RED);
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

for dynamic date format,

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getDate));

public ArrayList<String> getDate() {

        ArrayList<String> label = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++)
            label.add(yourList.get(i).getDateValue());
        return label;
    }
```